# OS freeze while trying to send UDP packet from linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, udp

I'm modifying UDP to implement a custom protocol. After UDP connect establishes a route, I want to send a custom UDP packet to the destination (like a SYN packet in TCP). When I try the connect() socket function on a machine running my custom kernel, it freezes without writing out anything to the kernel log. Here's my code

```
int quic_connect(struct sock *sk, struct flowi4 *fl4, struct rtable *rt){
    struct sk_buff *skb, *buff;
    struct inet_cork cork;  
    struct ipcm_cookie ipc;
    struct sk_buff_head queue;
    char *hello;
    int err = 0, exthdrlen, hh_len, datalen, trailerlen;
    char *data;

    hh_len = LL_RESERVED_SPACE(rt->dst.dev);
    exthdrlen = rt->dst.header_len;
    trailerlen = rt->dst.trailer_len;
    datalen = 200;

    //Create a buffer to be send without fragmentation
    skb = sock_alloc_send_skb(sk,
            exthdrlen + datalen + hh_len + trailerlen + 15,
            MSG_DONTWAIT, &err);
    if (skb == NULL)
        goto out;

    skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_PARTIAL;      // Use hardware checksum
    skb->csum = 0;
    skb_reserve(skb, hh_len);
    skb_shinfo(skb)->tx_flags = 1;          //Time stamp the packet 


    /*
     *  Find where to start putting bytes.
     */
    data = skb_put(skb, datalen + exthdrlen);
    skb_set_network_header(skb, exthdrlen);
    skb->transport_header = (skb->network_header +
                 sizeof(struct iphdr));

    __skb_queue_head_init(&queue);
    /*
     * Put the packet on the pending queue.
     */
    __skb_queue_tail(&queue, skb);

    cork.flags = 0;
    cork.addr = 0;
    cork.opt = NULL;
    ipc.opt = NULL;
    ipc.tx_flags = 0;
    ipc.ttl = 0;
    ipc.tos = -1;
    ipc.addr = fl4->daddr;
    err = ip_setup_cork(sk, &cork, &ipc, &rt);

    buff = __ip_make_skb(sk, fl4, &queue, &cork);
    kfree(skb);
    err = PTR_ERR(buff);
    if (!IS_ERR_OR_NULL(buff))
        err = udp_send_skb(buff, fl4);    

out:                                     
    return err;                      

}
```

The function `quic_connect` is called at the end of the `ip4_datagram_connect` function which is the registered handler for UDP connect.

There is absolutely nothing in the kernel log.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT 1: **The problem occurs at `err = udp_send_skb(buff, fl4);` as there is no issue when I comment out that line. so I'm assuming my sk_buff has not been formed correctly. Any ideas why?